# bash terminal/console strange overlapping behavior

Tags: gnome-terminal

I am using gnome-terminal in Ubuntu 11.10 and seem to get long lines overlapping
in the terminal window.

When I copy a long command line and paste it into the terminal, the text gets overlapped
to the start of the line and often covers the user prompt.

If I resize the terminal window, making it wider the overlapping gets undone and everything looks normal. In previous versions of Ubuntu, if a line was too long
it would continue on the next line below.

Another problem I have noticed that may be related, is when using the up arrow key
to show previously typed commands, sometimes instead of the output command line
being replaced by the previous command each time the key is pressed, the lines get
partially merged. A portion of the old line remains, and the next command gets
joined onto the end.

This leftover part of a command is persistent and does not get replaced next time the key is pressed, although the insertion point or blinking cursor is at the end of the
latest recalled command, and the leftover has no effect if I press enter.

Is this problem a bug or some setting that needs fixing?
Where do I look for the cause?
keyboard? gnome-terminal? bash?

Thank you for any help or suggestions offered

Comment: Can you confirm this happens on other units as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SOLVED]
I tested for this behaviour using the Ubuntu 11.10 live cd and did not have the same
problems in terminal, so I guessed that a change I had made was likely to be the cause.

I had made some changes to the .bashrc file while following a tutorial on customising the
bash user prompt, which must have caused this problem.

After restoring the original .bashrc file from backup, the problem with overlapping lines
is resolved.

Thanks for your response Huckle.
Cheers

Comment: I have since found another question posted here, which is nearly identical as far as the problem is concerned, but uses a different more accurate description. The info in that post is very useful. http://askubuntu.com/questions/81239/terminal-line-glitches

Answer (score 2):

The issue is when some non-printed characters are not properly enclosed by `\[ \]`.

make sure every option for colour, bold, underline etc is properly enclosed